# Reflection with lambda expression

Tags: reflection, entity-framework-4, lambda

I want to pass in a method three parameters. The Classname (table), the field and the keyword.

Then I would like to take with Entity Framework with reflection the table and find the fields that have the keyword.

Something like

```
public List<object> FilterOptions(string keyword, string className, string field)
        {
            var objectSet = (System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<dynamic>)DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(className).GetValue(DataContext, null);
            var options = objectSet.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(x, null) == keyword).ToList();
...
        }
```

However I get "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

When I change `<dynamic>` to `<object>` I get an error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is where you want to end up. You are wanting field names for your entities?

there is a property on the ObjectContext class called MetadataWorkspace. You can drill down to an EntitySet which has a property call MetadataProperties. Something like this.

```
public List<object> FilterOptions(string keyword, string className, string field)
{
    return ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace).BaseEntitySets.Where(es => es.MetadataProperties.Any(mp => mp.Name == keywork));
    // This has not been tested but should get you on the right path.
}
```

see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.entityset.aspx).

Hope this helps.

P.S. I also would recommend accepting more of your answers. You only have a 33% accept rate. Which means your question will eventually just get passed by. Remember if you found the answer somewhere else you can answer your own question. :0)